# UK distinction in Masters / 1st at UK undergraduate: are they of equal weighting?

Tags: masters, undergraduate, united-kingdom

UK Distinction in Masters / 1st at UK Undergraduate: are they, ceteris paribus, of equal weighting when assessing academic potential, in e.g. postgrad applications?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Can you explain what "1st at Undergraduate" means?

Comment: wow, ok, i mean a 1st at undergraduate. maybe a uk thing? @Ric

Comment: the idea of someone posting on a @acaedemia board when they don't know what a 1st is, is at best surprising

Comment: it's what our entire undergraduate system is based around

Comment: There's no need to be a jerk. I only have experience in the American school system and am just trying to help you improve your question.

Comment: @user3293056, do you assume everyone knows the UK HE system? That's obviously a false assumption.

Comment: @Ric touche, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a first class degree and a distinction at master's level is a great thing together. Separately, for a postgrad application it really depends. A distinction in a master's program related to the Ph.D. is going to give great weight to your application, even if your undergrad performance isn't as strong. When it's the other way round and the undergrad performance is fantastic but the master's research is not so good, it suggests the student is a great student, but maybe not cut out for research.